# How can i check for specific window name while enumerating EnumChildProc in WinApi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

So far i have been using GetClassName() to get a window handle with the class name that interested me while enumerating with EnumChildProc() but right now i am in situation where plenty of HWND's use the same classname so only way to identify my window i assume would be with its name which is unique.

So while i am enumerating i was thinking to use something like...

If getwindowname() == what i need... but i have no idea what function can i use for this, is there a function like getwindowname() that i can use in this enumeration?

Comment: What do you mean by "window name?" Are you referring to the Window caption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

this.. worked

```
TCHAR winname[MAX_PATH];
long lenght;
HWND hwndineed;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

lenght = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, 99, (LPARAM)winname); 

        if(wcscmp(winname, _T("caption i needed")) == 0)
        {
            hwndineed= hwnd;
            return FALSE; // end enumeration
        }
}
```

Comment: just using getwindowtext wont work if hwnd is from other app(which was my case)

Comment: well, sorry then i thought you were trying to lead me to something practical instead just finding what caption of window is, since i said i need to diferientate window by its name its logical that i already know the name so i also have no clue what you tried to asy